# Testing Django Models leads to TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

I am currently testing this model:

**models.py**

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name or ''

    @property
    def tags(self):
        tags = self.tagging.values('tag')
        return tags.values('tag_id', 'tag__name', 'tag__language')
```

With these tests:

**test_models.py**

```
class TagTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.tag_name = "name of the tag"
        self.tag_language = "language of tag"
        self.tag = Tag.objects.create(name=self.tag_name, language=self.tag_language)

    def test_name_label(self):
        tag = Tag.objects.get(name=self.tag_name)
        field_label = tag._meta.get_field('name').verbose_name()
        self.assertEqual(field_label, 'name')

    def test_tag_size(self):
        tag = Tag.objects.get(name=self.tag_name)
        max_length = tag._meta.get_field('name').max_length
        self.assertEqual(max_length, 256)

    def test_str(self):
        """Test for string representation"""
        self.assertEqual(str(self.tag), self.tag.name)
```

I currently get the following error for the method test_name_label(self):

```
FAILED frontend/tests/test_models.py::TagTests::test_name_label - TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

How can I get rid of it? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Field.verbose_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#verbose-name) is a string, not a method. Just remove parenthesis from it:

```
field_label = tag._meta.get_field('name').verbose_name
```